# Could two planetesimals orbit a dense object and share an atmosphere?

Tags: gravity, hypothetical

Could two objects be caught into an orbit around some kind of dense object, perhaps a rogue planet. Could they share an atmosphere.

[image: planetesimals]

Comment: What's your previous research on this topic? Please use question marks when posing questions. Also this maybe fits better into worldbuilding.se

Comment: Not "rouge" - "rogue". :-)

Comment: We have a “rouge” planet in our own Solar System ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how much do you know about drag? Orbits in atmosphere are short lived - as reference see any low earth orbit satellite. They need regular boosts or else they fall in.

So your objects could orbit... Briefly.

But not in the way you have drawn in the diagram, and not for any length of time.

Basically it's a no, in any real terms.